# How do enums behave with its subtypes using heap or stack types?

Tags: rust

The question title might be a bit misleading because I do not know how to word it correctly in terms of what I meant to say.

Here is the problem. I have this piece of code, and it works as expected.

```rust
enum Answer {
    Yes,
    No(i32),
}

pub struct QnA {
    question: String,
    answer: Answer,
}

fn check(qna: &QnA) {
    match qna.answer {
        Answer::Yes => println!("positive"),
        Answer::No(why) => println!("negative cause {}", why),
    }
}
```

What I am interested in is the `match` part. Let's say I changed the enum `Answer` to something like this,

```rust
enum Answer {
    Yes,
    No(String),
}
```

The match would no longer work. It says it cannot move out something which is behind a reference. To make it work, I have to use a referenced `&qna.answer` on the match.

I know the error only happens on heap used types. So I can get a cue that it is because of the ownership system, but I can't intuitively work out how with the enum and structs in between. I don't know how do enums behave with its subtypes using heaps or stacks.

Answer (score 5):

> I know the error only happens on heap used types.

This is untrue. The error happens on types which don't implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), which means that they must be moved. `i32` and most other primitives implement `Copy`, which means that you're free to pattern match on a reference and implicitly copy a non-reference value. However, with a non-`Copy` value like `String`, the implicit copy no longer happens and you attempt to move a value out of a reference, which is not allowed.

See:

- [*The Rust Programming Language: What is Ownership?*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)
- [*Rust by example: Ownership and moves*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/move.html)
- [*Rust Documentation: When can my type be `Copy`?*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-can-my-type-be-copy) (and the subsequent "When *can't* my type be `Copy`?" and "When *should* my type be `Copy`?")

As a bit of a side note, Rust's typesystem doesn't differentiate between heap-types and stack-types because those are unnecessary distinctions. The heap is just a chunk of memory like the stack that some memory allocator determines the use of, and in the core library, there is no heap allocator. *Generally*, only types on the stack implement `Copy`, since those are cheap to copy whereas heap memory would have to be reallocated. However, this is not to say that *every* type on the stack implements `Copy` (you can make a struct on the stack and not implement Copy on it), or that *no* types on the heap implement `Copy` (you could have a custom allocator or a garbage collector).

Comment: I think that the OP confusion comes from the Book saying (in that chapter you link): "Rust has a special annotation called the Copy trait that we can place on types like integers that are stored on the stack". It seems to equal stack-allocated with `Copy`.

Comment: @rodrigo Good point. I've edited some clarification into my answer.